# company mode does not start backends?

Tags: company-mode

Recently, I have tried setting up a JS development environment and part of that process has been configuring company-mode for autocompletion duties - but I'm having some issues triggering auto completion. First - here's the file I use to configure company mode:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure t
  :diminish yas-minor-mode
  :config
  (setq yas-snippet-dirs (append yas-snippet-dirs
                                 '("~/.emacs.d/snippets/")))
  (yas-global-mode 1))


(use-package company
  :ensure t
  :diminish company-mode
  :config
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-elisp)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-yasnippet)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dabbrev)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dabbrev-code)
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-etags)
  (setq company-auto-complete nil
        company-tooltip-flip-when-above t
        company-minimum-prefix-length 2
        company-tooltip-limit 10
        company-idle-delay 0.5)
  (global-company-mode 1))
;;  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'company-mode))

(use-package helm-company
  :ensure t
  :config
  (progn
    (define-key company-mode-map (kbd "C-:") 'helm-company)
    (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-:") 'helm-company)))

(use-package company-tern
  :ensure t
  :init
  (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-tern))


(use-package tern
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :diminish tern-mode
  :config
  (progn
    (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'tern-mode)))

(provide 'init-autocompletion)
```

Now, let's say I'm working in a...Coffeescript file - and it has something like this:

```
foo = 
  addTwo: (a) ->
    a + 2
  addThree: (a) ->
    a + 3
```

then later on in that file I start typing:

```
foo.a...
```

I would hope that company would kick in and offer addTwo/Three as candidates - but I got nada!

I ran company-diag - and I get this:

```
Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0) of 2015-07-13 on MFT-A018.local
Company 0.9.0-cvs

company-backends: (company-tern company-etags company-dabbrev-code company-yasnippet company-elisp company-bbdb company-nxml company-css company-eclim company-semantic company-clang company-xcode company-cmake company-capf
              (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
              company-oddmuse company-files company-dabbrev)

Used backend: company-etag
```

and a whole bunch of completion candidates - none of which are foo.addTwo/Three

can anyone offer any advice on how to get company-mode working?

Comment: Does `tern` support CoffeeScript? I don't think it does ATM.

Comment: no, but shouldn't dabbrev or dabbrev-code offer some candidates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `company-backends` is a variable defined in `company.el`.
>
> Documentation:
>   The list of active back-ends (completion engines).
>
> **Only one back-end is used at a time.**  The choice depends on the order of
>   the items in this list, and on the values they return in response to the
>   ‘prefix’ command (see below).  **But a back-end can also be a "grouped"
>   one (see below).**
>
> Grouped back-ends:
>
> An element of `company-backends` can also itself be a list of back-ends,
>   then it's considered to be a "grouped" back-end.
>
> When possible, commands taking a candidate as an argument are dispatched to
>   the back-end it came from.  In other cases, the first non-nil value among
>   all the back-ends is returned.
>
> The latter is the case for the `prefix` command.  But if the group contains
>   the keyword `:with`, the back-ends after it are ignored for this command.
>
> The completions from back-ends in a group are merged (but only from those
>   that return the same `prefix`).

Tl;DR

For some reason, `company-etags` thinks it's handling completion for the current buffer. Since it comes earlier in the list than `company-dabbrev-code`, it gets priority.

One way to handle this is to use mode-hooks to force the backend list to match what you'd like.

Another way is to throw a set of backends into a group. Members of a group do not block each other, so as long as `company-dabbrev-code` is in the first group it will always be active. This has its drawbacks too (performance, for example), and you will have to weigh between the two.

I use a sort of hybrid combination of the two. Unfortunately, my setup uses a lot of macro magic so it doesn't really make sense on its own.

EDIT: Here's a solution for CoffeeScript:

```el
(add-hook 'coffee-mode
  (lambda ()
    (setq company-backends '(company-dabbrev-code))))
```

Comment: Apparently, the author of the question has a TAGS file in that project. So `company-etags` indeed thinks it should be used. Since it is in the beginning of `company-backends` for some reason (as opposed to the default configuration), nothing else gets used.

Comment: in all honesty, I have just thrown some completion backends in there that I thought might work - I come from Sublime/Vim where this isn't really an issue - so it's a little hard for me to grok at this stage. @PythonNut - could you show me an example of how you might start dabbrev-code for a specific mode?

Comment: @sunwukung does the edit help?